# Entity Framework related objects insertion with stored procedure and auto_increment field

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, foreign-keys, ria, auto-increment

I have a problem inserting a related row through Entity Framework 5. I'm using it with RIA Services and .NET Framework version 4.5. The database system is MySQL 5.6. The connector version is 6.6.5.

**It raises a Foreign Key constraint exception.**

I've chosen to simplify the model to expose my issue.

> **LDM**
>
> Provider(id, name, address)
>
> Article(id, name, price)
>
> LinkToProvider(provider_id, article_id, provider_price)
>
> // Id's are auto_increment columns.

First I create a new instance of Article. I add an instance of LinkToProvider to the LinkProvider collection of the article. In this LinkToProvider object the product itself is referenced. An existing provider is also referenced.
Then I submit the changes.

> **Sample code from the DataViewModel**

```
this.CurrentArticle = new Article();

...

this.CurrentArticle.LinkToProvider.Add(

new LinkToProvider { Article = this.CurrentArticle, Provider = 
this.ProviderCollection.CurrentItem }

);

...

this.DomainContext.articles.Add(this.CurrentArticle);

this.DomainContext.SubmitChanges();
```

**NOTE :**

At the begining Entity Framework inserts the product well. Then it fails because it tries to insert a row in the LinkToPrivder table with an unkown product id like the following.

```
INSERT
INTO LinkToProvider
VALUES(5, 0, 1.2)
```

It puts 0 instead of the generated id.

But if I insert a product alone without any relations the product id is generated in the database correctly.

Any help will be much appreciated !
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. 
You need to **bind the result** from the stored procedure to the id column **in the edmx model**

So I have to modify my stored procedure to add an instruction to show the last instered id for the article table on the standard output.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS NewArticleId;
```

Then I added the binding with the name of the column name returned by the stored procedure. Here it's NewArticleId.

It's explained here : http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/using-stored-procedures-for-insert-update-amp-delete-in-an-entity-data-model/.